# I am getting deprecated error when building my apps

Tags: flutter, gradle, dart

I am trying to build my app but all the time it shows me these errors i dont know what to do.. Please read bellow :

```
E:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\share-0.6.5+1\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\share\SharePlugin.java:14: warning: [deprecation] PluginRegistry in io.flutter.plugin.common has been deprecated
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry.Registrar;
                               ^
E:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\share-0.6.5+1\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\share\SharePlugin.java:14: warning: [deprecation] PluginRegistry in io.flutter.plugin.common has been deprecated
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry.Registrar;
                               ^
error: warnings found and -Werror specified
1 error
2 warnings

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':share:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2m 36s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error,I fixed it by updating camera pacakage(https://pub.dev/packages/camera) to version ^0.5.8+8.